# Creating a custom field constructor in Play 2 (scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to grok the instructions given [in the play 2 scala tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers) for form template helpers. I am getting stuck in the section "Writing your own field constructors". It gives a sample template (without saying what the name of the file should be):

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Then it shows this code:

```
object MyHelpers {
  implicit val myFields = FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f)    
}
```

I am confused about how this is supposed to relate to the template. (eg, is the template file supposed to be called myFieldConstructorTemplate.scala.html?) I tried some variations on this without luck.

I'm new to both scala and Play, but I also know play 2 and its docs are new, so I'm not sure what incredibly obvious thing I'm missing.

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calling it `myFieldConstructorTemplate.scala.html`? Because that is how it should work, as far as I know.

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/twitterBootstrap/package.scala -- I see this file that could be some help to understand initializing field constructor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the tutorial this code is along the text:

> Often you will need to write your own field constructor. Start by
>   writing a template like:

This means you have to create your own template (`xxxx.scala.html`) and add that code inside. After that, you import it in your template with the code they provide  (remember to add that to each scala template that uses your custom field):

```
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(xxxx.f) }
```

Check the samples of Play, the Forms sample uses a similar approach with Twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Hmm, this was the first thing I tried and it didn't work. Typo, maybe? I'll give it another go. Thanks!

Comment: Docs for 2.4 suggest  `implicit val myFields = FieldConstructor(html.xxxx.f)`. I created `xxxx.scala.html` in the `views` directory with my other templates, so I needed `implicit val myFields = FieldConstructor(views.html.xxxx.f)`.

Answer (score 17):

I've just had the same problem, I agree with you the documentation is not clear at all...

**Possible error 1**

```
not found: value FieldConstructor
```

It means that you haven't imported the helper with this instruction :

```
@import helper._
```

**Possible error 2**

```
not found: value implicitConstructor
```

It means that you are declaring the field constructor in the wrong place in your template (i.e. : in the @helper.form method). To fix this, I declared my field constructor just after my import instructions :

```
@import form._
@import helper._

@implicitConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(foundation_field.render) }
```

(My foundation_field.scala.html file is in the views.form package).

Answer (score 0):

To follow the logic of Scala implicit keyword, the document is implicit too ;)

Scala and Play are too immature right now, for that reason the documentation is very poor.

This SOF answer is very good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268122/1163081

You can also check the Play source for more examples: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/html/

Or this guys appears to discover the solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/2e1EqZJ-Qks/gXD1oo0IjfcJ