# textfield with scala play form helper

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, textfield

Scala form helper is not as consistent as I would expect

```
@form(action = routes.Admin.insertNewArticle, 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
  <fieldset>
    @textarea(field = articleForm("text"), args = 'rows -> 3, 'cols -> 50)
    @input(articleForm("author"), "author")
  </fieldset> 
}
```

The `input` fields look really nice and have labels on the left with fields on the right. But the `textarea` is just weird, it's not wrapped in a `<div>` with a label, but it's in a `<dl>` tag and at the bottom there's a 'Required' sign that I don't know how to remove.

Here's the image of how it looks:

[image]

Any tips on how I can get the form to look consistent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options.

First, you can override the helper to just put in your own hand-rolled HTML for the textarea control.  This is described in the documentation under ["Using the form template helpers"](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaFormHelpers) under the section "Handling HTML input creation yourself", and common pitfalls are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392302/creating-a-custom-field-constructor-in-play-2-scala). If you want a div containing a label, you'd do something like this:

```
@helper.input(field = articleForm("text")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <div>
        <label>text</label>
        <textarea name="@name" id="@id" rows='3' cols='50'>@value</textarea>
    </div>
}
```

You can also use CSS to style the default HTML produced by the `textarea` helper.  The `<dl>` tag is simply a [definition list](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) and can by styled much like any html list.  For reference, you can find the default field constructor code in [github](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/defaultFieldConstructor.scala.html), which shows you what the generated html looks like.

I assume that the "Required" sign you're talking about is the error `<dd>` tag you can see in that generated HTML.  If you aren't going the hand-rolled HTML route, then to get rid of it you'll need to define your own field constructor.  That is also described in the Play help page I linked to above.  But if all you care about is getting rid of the error, it should be pretty easy, just make a copy of the default field constructor code (also linked above), and alter or just remove the parts that read `@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}` and the three lines starting with `@elements.errors(elements.lang).map`. The "Required" error itself is from `@elements.infos...`.

Or is the problem that this field is *not* supposed to be required?  That is an issue with the form definition, not the helper.  Make the "text" field in your form optional, as shown on the [Scala Forms help page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaForms) under "Optional values". For example, if your task definition is in `Application.scala`:

```
   val taskForm = Form (
     "text" -> optional(text) // changed from 'nonEmptyText'
   )
```

This will also make the "text" field map to an `Option[String]` instead of a plain `String`. If your form is backed by a case class (or other mapping logic), you'll have to change it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I had to add a custom field constructor, but the tutorial seems very unclear about how to name files and where to put some things. But I have it working now. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share how did you do it ?!

Comment: @zidarsk8 I'm having the same problem with the Play documentation. It's very hand-wavy and generic, with no concrete examples of exactly how to do things.