# PlayFramework 2.1: Validation Form (error messages)

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm developing an application in PlayFramework 2.1. But, I'm not using Form helpers, like: @inputText, I'm writing my own HTML.

How can I display error messages without using the Form Helper? Because, if I use the form helper, the error messages is showed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the official documentation there is a brief explanation on how to write you own inputs (for example) without default helpers, check the "Writting your own field contructor" section [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFormHelpers)

I'm adding an example on how to write your own template to this post to clarify a bit, in response to your second comment. This example adds a bit to what is explained in the official documentation.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392302/creating-a-custom-field-constructor-in-play-2-scala) is related to this question and is helpful too.

First, you have to create a template, to do this, go to /app/views/afolderyoulike and create myField.scala.html (for example). Add this example code, which you can tune as you wish:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, the view where you have your Form, would look something like the code this:

```
@(title: String, formSignup: Form[models.commerce.CommerceSignupRequest])

@import play.data.Form
@import helper._

@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myField.f) }

@main(title) {
    <div class="container">
        @form(action = routes.CommerceController.signup()) {
            <fieldset>
                <legend>@title</legend>
                @inputText(formSignup("commerceName"))
                @inputText(formSignup("blabla1"))
                @inputText(formSignup("blabla2"))
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" name="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
        }
    </div>
}
```

The important pieces of code here are:

- @import helper._  which brings default @inputText.
- @implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myField.f) } imports your template
- @inputText(formSignup("commerceName")) which renders your customized template replacing those default inputText we don't want to use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I write this code in my view? there is anyway to alter helper bootstrap?

Comment: That code provided is an example, you can use elements.field to get the corresponding field and elements.errors to get the errors (if there where any when you submitted the form) and handle them as you may need without using inputText.

Comment: Ok, nice...Just one more thing...if, I add: @(elements: helper.FieldElements) on my template, I get a compilation error: not found: value elements

Comment: Lücks, I added an example with a customized inputField. Sorry for my late response, I had a very busy day. :)